# Load Balanced File Access without the Cloud

Tags: microservices, storage

I have an application made up of several microservices to allow independent pieces to be scaled up/down as needed (running as containers in docker swarm and maybe eventually kubernetes). I'm looking for any suggestions for controlling access to a shared file system from multiple containers as I feel like there is probably some system/software out there that I just don't know how to search for it.

Data in the form of physical files will come in to a single location. I need to have one microservice read each file that comes in and basically upload it to a database.

**What solutions exist, if any, that would prevent 2 or more instances of the same microservice from fighting over each file?**

This will need to work in a 100% offline environment so cloud storage is not an option. Ideally it would work similar to how a message queue works in that the next available consumer would pick up the next available file from this shared file system.